# Diffusion with randomly distributed initial condition

Tags: calculus, probability, ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

From the material/books/etc. that I have read - an Ito diffusion always has a fixed initial condition
$$
dX(t)= \mu dt +  \sigma dW(t) \hspace{10mm}  (1) \\
X(0)=x_0 
$$

Does it make sense to model a diffusion with a normally distributed initial condition as an example
$$
dX(t)= \mu dt +  \sigma dW(t) \hspace{10mm}  (2)\\ 
X(0)= N(0,1)
$$

**Additional information 1**:

According to this Wiki article [Kolmogorov backward equations (diffusion)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_backward_equations_(diffusion))

> Informally, the Kolmogorov forward equation addresses the following problem. We have information about the state $x$ of the system at time $t$ (namely a probability distribution $p_{t}(x))$; we want to know the probability distribution of the state at a later time $s>t$. The adjective 'forward' refers to the fact that $p_{t}(x)$ serves as the initial condition and the PDE is integrated forward in time. **(In the common case where the initial state is known exactly $p_{t}(x)$ is a Dirac delta function centered on the known initial state).**

So, when the initial state of the diffusion is not known (FK initial condition is not delta)- then what is the representation of the initial state diffusion (equation 1)?

**Additional information 2**:

> Monte Carlo in probability theory:
>
> Let $g(x)$ be a function of a random variable $X$, then 
>   $$
> E[g(x)]= \intop\nolimits_{-\infty }^{\infty} g(x)f(x)dx
> $$
>
> Where $f(x)$ is the probability distribution of $X$.

Now, assume $g(x,t)$ is the solution of the [Feynman-Kac formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula)

$$
 \frac{\partial g(x,t)}{\partial t} = -v(x)g(x,t) + \mu \frac{\partial g(x,t)}{\partial t} + \frac{ \sigma^2 }{2}  \frac{\partial^2 g(x,t) }{\partial x^2} \hspace{10mm}  (3)
$$
Example graph:
[image: FK Solution]

The blue line (or any parallel line to it) in the graph gives us the conditional solution $[g(x,t)|X(0)=x]$ - specifically $X(0)=0$ in this case.

Ok, great now imagine that I am modeling a system of (100 particles or items).

1. Each particle follows the diffusion model defined for $X(t)$ in (1).
2. Also, suppose that I have solved the Feynman-Kac for the function $g(x,t)$ but I do not know exactly the initial condition of each particle.
3. But, I do know that their initial condition follows a distribution i.e.: $f(x_0) \approx N(0,1)$.

So, if I want to find an average solution $E[g(x,t)]$, I suppose i can write the following:

> $$
> E[g(x,t)]= \intop\nolimits_{-\infty }^{\infty} g(x,t|X(0)=x_0)f(x_0)dx \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=i}^{N}g(x^i,t)  \hspace{10mm}  (4)
> $$

Thus, if I were to simulate $10,000$ diffusion paths $(N=10000)$ with $X(0)=N(0,1)$ - would approximate the integral.

So, in this context how wrong am I?

Comment: Yes of course, as long as you can specify the relationship of the initial normal random variable and the Wiener process (say independent). The initial normal random variable just serve as a random displacement of the process, for independent case.

Comment: @BGM Can you please look at the additional information. Thank you so much!